# Javascript generated html element to load resources from a specific hostname

Tags: javascript, html

I create an HTML element from a string to parse something from it

```
html = document.createElement('html');
html.innerHTML = 'some html string loaded from a different host';
```

but I see that the resources loaded using an absolute path without hostname, try to be loaded from the current window location.

Is there a way to set a specific location from where to load the resources without having to replace all absolute or relative src paths?

for example if I have an image in the html string

```
<img src="/abspathto/img.jpg">
```

when I create the html element and set its innerHTML, the browser tries to load the image from the current hostname/abspathto/img.jpg

I want to be able to set from which host name the browser can load the images that have only the pathname on their src on that html element generated from javascript.

Comment: You should have a root folder for your application then you can just do `<img src="/images/path/to/img">`. If you don't have an immediate one, then you can absolute a path like you have done `<img src="https://www.something.com/image.jpg">` or you can reference one on your computer `<img src="C:/users/another/path/img.jpg">`.

Comment: did you mean to have path dynamic updated? but how did you create HTML String?

Comment: code you share is not sufficient enough, can you share full and exact code

Comment: I've added a code example of how I create the html element. I want to set from which host the browser can load the images using the relative or abspath, so that it doesn't try to load them from <current location.hostname>/path/to/img. Since I'm running the code from a web extension background script I get a lot of network errors of not found resources because I can't set the correct hostname from which to load them. I want to know if it's possible to this with search and replace to add the correct hostname on every src

Answer (score 0):

So, it is **best practice to use relative file paths** (if possible).
The reason why is that it will work regardless of hostname, meaning it would also work in any stage of development or deployment as long as the directory structure does not change.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

You can control which level at which HTML starts at by using double dots (i.e "../images/path/to/img", this goes up 1 directory).

You can use a website such as: "https://www.stackoverflowexample.com/images/path/to/img.jpg"

You can use another computer's resources using UNC path or IP address if the user that is accessing them has permission to do so. Stack overflow answer on that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29257902/8570546

This should allow you to navigate to any resource you have access to using HTML File Paths.